# best way to handle when a game is active?

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem with a game I'm making on C#. I have a status for the game to decide if it's active or not.

However, there are many moments when it must be paused

- don't have focus
- a menu is opened
- moving the window
- not visible

It's starting to be lots of checks to lots of place to have those conditions working.

I'm trying to do like FCEUX which is genial.

Right now I need the following event from the form:

OnDeactivate, OnActivated. Then, if clicking on a menu, the form is activated but needs to be stop. I then need to also include events for when a menu is clicked.

Then someone can move the application with the mouse, this also requires another event... and on and on...

Comment: So what's the problem? You can't write the function in one place to be used in others? You can put the call closer to the start of your update loop?

Comment: what I'm doing, but I felt like I was maybe missing a simpler event to do it... it seems a little "spaghetti"

Comment: You'll need to describe more of what you want and what you have now. Otherwise this question is pretty open-ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set some boolean value indicating you should pause your game when you detect any of the conditions you listed. It sounds like you're using Windows Forms; this means you can detect all of your conditions as follows:

- "don't have focus" Listen for the [activated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx) and [deactivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate(v=vs.110).aspx) events. A form must be activated to have input focus.
- "a menu is opened" This is tricky, as games generally don't *have* OS-style menus, and those that do don't generally need to pause when they open. That said, you can probably hook [`MenuStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.menustart(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect this and [`MenuComplete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.menucomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) to resume the game.
- "moving the window" There are events for [starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin(v=vs.110).aspx) and stopping a [resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizebegin(v=vs.110).aspx) operation; these fire when moving the form as well and so should cover all those cases.
- "not visible" Look at [`VisibleChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Some classes of low-level events aren't exposed to you via the Windows Forms API. In those cases you'll need to manual handle them in a `WndProc`; that means subclassing the `Form` class and overriding the [`WndProc` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) correctly (make sure to call the base class version if you don't handle the message yourself). That will let you detect clicks in the title bar and other non-client areas of the form (handle [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620(v=vs.85).aspx) and the corresponding button-up message).

I'm not sure if the `NC` messages will fire when you click the system menu; in general it doesn't seem like you can get a message for that menu opening (probably because "you don't own it"). Your best bet may be to disable that menu in your window style.

It's true you'll be adding a fair number of hooks for all the events and scenarios you want covered to pause your game, but there isn't much you can do about that (other than to decide you don't care about pausing for some conditions). As long as your factoring out the actual code for handling the pause, and only setting some kind of `shouldPause` variable to true or false in the bodies of all these event handlers, it shouldn't be *that* big of a maintenance burden.

Comment: this is working well so far. I'm howeve searching for 2 events: when is the title bar of the form clicked and when is the context menu of the title bar opened/closed?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim I updated the answer with some information on that.

Comment: thanks! I found those exact event, however as you say I can't get message for the System Menu. Thanks however the reason makes it clears why it happens. I have one last problem now, maybe you would know? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463170/how-to-know-if-a-menu-item-is-selected?noredirect=1#comment64330933_38463170

After that everything is handled correctly.
For the system menu bar, I only lock engine when moving the application with mouse.